# How to display the total number of quantity in the input box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a quantity field. The user can add multiple quantity fields on click on Add button.
[image]

My issue is, I have to display the total number of quantity in the input box. for example I added 10 quantity in the quantity box and the total is 10 in the total box.

[image]

The user can increase and decrease the quantity on click on plus and minus button as well as direct enter then quantity in the quantity box and total will display in the total box.

[image]

The user can add multiple quantities field same as on remove. I click on to remove the quantity should be removed from the total quantity field.

[image]

You can also check my code here as well https://jsfiddle.net/pu6qy4zr/70/

```js
function increaseValue(n) {
  var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('number' + n).value, 10);
  value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
  value++;
  document.getElementById('number' + n).value = value;

}

function decreaseValue(n) {
  var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('number' + n).value, 10);
  value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
  value < 1 ? value = 1 : '';
  value--;
  document.getElementById('number' + n).value = value;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  var max_fields = 20; //maximum input boxes allowed
  var wrapper = $(".add_row"); //Fields wrapper
  var add_button = $(".add_row_click"); //Add button ID

  var x = 1; //initlal text box count
  $(add_button).click(function(e) { //on add input button click
    e.preventDefault();
    if (x < max_fields) { //max input box allowed
      x++; //text box increment
      $("input[id^=medication_name]").focus();
      $(wrapper).append('<div class="custom_fields"><div class="col-md-6"><div class="row"><div class="col-md-6"><div class="form_group"><div class="plus_minus"><span class="value_button decrease" onclick="decreaseValue(' + x + ')" value="Decrease Value"> - </span><input type="number" id="number' + x + '" class="qty_number form_control" name="qty_number[]" class="form_control" value="0" /><span class="value_button increase" onclick="increaseValue(' + x + ')" value="Increase Value"> + </span></div></div></div><div class="col-md-6"><div class="form_group"> <div class="btn_row remove_field"> <span> - </span> Remove  </div></div></div></div></div></div></div>');
    }
  });

  $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function(e) { //user click on remove text
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('.custom_fields').remove();
    x--;
  })


});
```

```html
<div class="add_row">
  <div class="plus_minus">
    <span class="value_button decrease" onclick="decreaseValue(1)" value="Decrease Value">-</span>
    <input type="number" id="number1" class="qty_number form_control" name="qty_number[]" value="0" class="form_control" />
    <span class="value_button increase" onclick="increaseValue(1)" value="Increase Value">+</span>

  </div>
  <div class="btn_row add_row_click"> <span> +  </span> Add </div>
</div>
<input type="text" class="form_control" name="total_qty" id="total_qty" value="" placeholder="Total number of quantity" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @vsync read the title of the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify all this.

- run `sum()` on each change including the remove and direct input/paste.
- only have one event handler for the plus/minus
- remove the inline handlers

PS: I found a bug: `value < 1 ? value = 1 : '';` would force a value of 1
PPS: I suggest you use .clone for the div instead of inserting it. Makes it much easier to update the HTML. Since I delegate and use relative addressing, you do not need to change the IDs of the fields

```js
function sum() {
  var total = 0;
  $(".qty_number").each(function() { // or use .map.get()
    total += this.value?parseInt(this.value):0;
  })
  $("#total_qty").val(total);
}


$(document).ready(function() {
  var max_fields = 20; //maximum input boxes allowed
  var $wrapper = $(".add_row"); //Fields wrapper
  var add_button = $(".add_row_click"); //Add button ID

  var x = 1; //initlal text box count
  $(add_button).on("click",function(e) { //on add input button click
    e.preventDefault();
    if (x < max_fields) { //max input box allowed
      x++; //text box increment
      $("input[id^=medication_name]").focus();
      $wrapper.append('<div class="custom_fields"><div class="col-md-6"><div class="row"><div class="col-md-6"><div class="form_group"><div class="plus_minus"><span class="value_button decrease" value="Decrease Value"> - </span><input type="number" id="number' + x + '" class="qty_number form_control" name="qty_number[]" class="form_control" value="0" /><span class="value_button increase" value="Increase Value"> + </span></div></div></div><div class="col-md-6"><div class="form_group"> <div class="btn_row remove_field"> <span> - </span> Remove  </div></div></div></div></div></div></div>');
    }
  });

  $wrapper.on("click", ".remove_field", function(e) { //user click on remove text
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('.custom_fields').remove();
    x--;
    sum(); // remove also updates the total
  })
  $wrapper.on("click",".value_button",function() {
    var $input = $(this).closest(".plus_minus").find(".qty_number");
    var value = parseInt($input.val(), 10);
    value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
    value+=$(this).is(".decrease")?-1:1; // decrease on increase dependent on class
    if (value < 0) value=0;
    $input.val(value);
    sum(); // sum each time
  });
  $wrapper.on("input",".qty_number",sum); // any input or paste
});
```

```html
<div class="add_row">
  <div class="plus_minus">
    <span class="value_button decrease" value="Decrease Value">-</span>
    <input type="number" id="number1" class="qty_number form_control" name="qty_number[]" value="0" class="form_control" />
    <span class="value_button increase" value="Increase Value">+</span>

  </div>
  <div class="btn_row add_row_click"> <span> +  </span> Add </div>
</div>
<input type="text" class="form_control" name="total_qty" id="total_qty" value="" placeholder="Total number of quantity" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, Give me some time to implement in my code.

Comment: Please note I just updated the code to handle the remove

Comment: Also I suggest you use .clone for the div instead of inserting it. Makes it much easier to update the HTML. Since I delegate and use relative addressing, you do not need to change the IDs of the fields

Comment: I am checking your code to understand. Also, I notice that you remove the increase and decrease function.

Comment: Yes, they are no longer needed. Also I JUST added `$(".plus_minus").on("input",".qty_number",sum);` since the fields are not read-only so the user can type a number without using the +/-

Comment: I consolidated the plus/minus into one function that tests `value+=$(this).is(".decrease")?-1:1;`

Comment: I got lots of information from your code and explanation. @mplungjan, big thank you. I will accept this answer and upvote you for finding the bugs in my code and you solved it within 5 min. I was finding the answer from last 2-3 days and you solved it.

Comment: Just little bit consern. When I am adding the direct quantity in the first than it's calculating but when I am adding dynamically field and adding quantity that is not working.

Comment: Ah, I was not delegating high enough. I had to delegate from wrapper, not the also dynamic plus_minus. Please see the update: `$(".add_row").on("input",".qty_number",sum);`

Comment: I have now consolidated on $wrapper (I alway prefix jquery objects with $)

Comment: sir, I need to know from where you learn the scripting? because I am struggling from last 2-3 days and you are solving that issue within 2 min... you code is working perfectly now.

Comment: Oh! that great!!  I am also learning the script form last 2 year but still don't understand it.

Comment: I have been programming since 1986 so I had some idea. My biggest issue these days is I was a procedural programmer and struggle a little with ES6 version of JS

Comment: Cool!! No problem. I will check it.

Comment: If you have a time please check my issue, I tried your above script and trying to display the value in the input field. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52351742/how-to-display-the-data-in-the-input-fields-which-are-dynamically-added